# pass different struct type for a function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

```
struct TypeA: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var dataArr: [TypeB]
 }

struct TypeB: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var data: Data
 }
```

I have those two structs and I want to pass them to a function like this, the problem is that sometimes I want to use TypeB in function call
and sometime I want to use TypeA, how can I do that?

```
func getData(typeB: TypeB){
//some code
}
```

I want to call the function like this at DataVC,
So I can use this data and append it to array for example

```
let typeB:TypeB?  
getData(typeB)
```

and call the function like this at EditVC,
So I can edit all the array

```
let typeA:TypeA?  
getData(typeA)
```

Comment: Depending on your use-case, overloading or abstractization are possible solutions. How do you plan to send the values to the functions? Can you give us some usage examples (event if they don't compile)?

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes I want to use TypeB in function call and sometime I want to use TypeA"? Can you show what you want to do in `getData`?

Comment: @Sweeper
I mean sometimes I want to use data of typeA and other time I want typeB only
edited my question

Comment: As mentioned, you can overload the function by having two functions with the same name but different arguments. `func getData(type: TypeA) {...}` and `func getData(type: TypeB) {...}`

Comment: You've shown how you want to use `getData`, but you still haven't shown what you want to do _in it_. What code do you intend to write inside `getData`? Specifically, how are you going to make use of the parameter that is either going to be `typeA` or `typeB`?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini yes, I solved it by your approach, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an enum with different cases and their associated values like:

```
enum ABType {
    case a(TypeA)
    case b(TypeB)
}
```

so you can implement the function like:

```
func getData(type: ABType) {
    switch type {
    case .a(let objectA): print(objectA.dataArr)
    case .b(let objectB): print(objectB.data)
    }
}
```

Also, you can fill the function like:

```
let typeA: TypeA?
...
getData(type: .a(typeA!))
```

```
let typeB: TypeB?  
...
getData(type: .b(typeB!))
```